# Routing via Laravel API

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a very small software and I use laravel and vue.js. I would like to know  the difference between routing though api.php and web.php in routes folder. Can somebody explain me the difference in these two cases?

Comment: One is for APIs and the other isn't, it's all in the docs. Be sure to check them out since Laravel's are actually really good: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is explained in the first sentence of the relevant framework documentation. The question isn't necessarily bad, but there's a severe lack of research from his/her side.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/structure#the-routes-directory

Answer (score 0):

You can define the routes in either web.php or api.php. However, routes in api.php have certain advantages

- routes get automatically prefixed with '/api/'
- routes use api-middleware and auth. This can add certain additional security by throttling API-requests.

You should use api.php for all your api needs or any routes that will be called through ajax.

: